# Make multiple public files back to private on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently I have a lot of files on Amazon S3 which are public.

I want to make all files in this bucket no longer public.

How do I do this?

On the UI, when you select multiple folders and click "More", there is an option to make them public, but none to make them un-public.

The only method I found is by manually going on to each file and changing each individual permission.

Comment: I would recommend a third party software product for this. Cloudberry supports this ability. Otherwise you can write a script to process each file one by one. In Python this is easy.

Comment: Put that as an answer as it's perfectly valid and does the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a third party software product for this. CloudBerry supports this ability. Otherwise you can write a script to process each file one by one. In Python this is easy.

[CloudBerry Explorer for S3](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/explorer/amazon-s3.aspx)

[AWS SDK for Python (Boto3)](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/)